# Cannot connect to SQL database using Blazor and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to setup a simple Blazor website that connects to a SQL Server database and I can't seem to get it to work, I get an error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient

when trying to query any of the database entities. Connecting to the same database and using the same `DBContext` works fine from a unit testing projects, I just can't make it work using Blazor.

In my program.cs I have:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IntegrationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"MyConnString"));
```

I even tried using an in-memory provider, which worked fine. I'm using .NET 6 and connecting to an Azure based SQL (although I did try connecting to a LocalDB instance, with the same results).

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to connect to SQL Server with connection string "MyConnString" as literal and not a variable.  `UseSqlServer($"{MyConnString}")` if `MyConnString` is a variable containing the actual conn string value.

Comment: The issue is the connection string.  Are you on the same machine with the same user account.  1) The user account has to be the same.  Just because the user name is the same doesn't mean the account are linked.  Usually in a corporation that uses Group Policy the accounts share the same password server 2) A database (mdf file) can be connected to a SQL Server or the mdf file may not be attached to server.  Only use LocalDb when the mdf file is not attached to a server.  Do not use LocalDb when the mdf file is attached to the server.

Comment: @jdweng No, the issue is that SqlClient is in principle [not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/599#issuecomment-648471541) in Blazor webassembly. The rest of your comment is completely unconnected to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS-SQL Client software uses a TCP socket based protocol that is indeed "not supported" on WebAssembly.

You would need a Db with an HTTP based API but then be very aware that your credentials will be public. A Web based Client is not secure.

This is why all SPA apps that need a backend Database use an API server for Db access. Take a look at the Blazor Wasm + Hosted template, see if that works for you.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't mentioned anywhere in the MS docs! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user12233209 [It is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-webassembly), and then again in [tad more details](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/wiki/Common-Problems-and-Solutions-in-Blazor#problem-blazor-wasm-restrictions).